# angular cli 7.1 can't create a new project, schema validation errror

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm was using angular cli 6+. Today i upgraded cli to 7.1 and tried to create a new application. I run the below command to create a new project

```
ng new my-first-project
```

I get the following error.

```
    Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"my-first-project"}
Errors:

  Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

Then i run the command like this.

```
ng new my-first-project --version=1.1
```

i get the error.

```
 Tree type is not supported.
```

following are my set up.

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.0
Node: 8.11.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.0
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.0
@schematics/angular          7.1.0
@schematics/update           0.11.0
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Am i missing something here?

thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23744

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10850

Comment: When i re-installed angular cli with the following command
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest. it seems to work. The version hasn't changed, the reinstalled worked for me

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

as it seems from the schematics schema.json, for ng-new command - schema defined as mandatory flag along with the name, check out the required section in the bottom of the schema.json file under the ng-new schematics folder,
probably this is the reason why you get the error about the required version:

> node_modules@schematics\angular\ng-new\schema.json

```
  "required": [
    "name",
    "version"
  ]
```

you can try to indicate the name flag specifically like this:

> ng new --name=my-first-project --version=1.1.0

though the name at index 0 (zero) without the need for a flag:

```
"name": {
  "description": "The name of the new workspace and initial project.",
  "type": "string",
  "format": "html-selector",
  "$default": {
    "$source": "argv",
    "index": 0
  },
  "x-prompt": "What name would you like to use for the new workspace and initial project?"
},
```